# Convert an http response application/pdf to Base64 encoding

Tags: node.js, base64, buffer

I have this REST multipart response:

```
--uuid:30f86629-9036-40cf-abf1-a04967a8255b
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns4:dualLabelResponse xmlns:ns4="http://v1.dual.crp.ws.returns.ipc.be/" xmlns:ns3="http://v1.crp.ws.returns.ipc.be/" xmlns:ns2="http://v1.common.crp.ws.returns.ipc.be/"><Response><itemBarcodeLeg12><barcode>CZ000002995BE</barcode><barcodeText>CZ000002995BE</barcodeText><barcodeSymbology>10</barcodeSymbology></itemBarcodeLeg12><routingCodeLeg12/><postByDateTime>2023-12-24T05:20:53.948Z</postByDateTime><issueDateTime>2023-10-25T05:20:53.948Z</issueDateTime><label><xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:0fe0cfe8-aec9-4224-92fc-6c3fda92ec4c-289@cxf.apache.org"/></label></Response></ns4:dualLabelResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:30f86629-9036-40cf-abf1-a04967a8255b
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <0fe0cfe8-aec9-4224-92fc-6c3fda92ec4c-289@cxf.apache.org>

%PDF-1.4
%����
2 0 obj
<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 48>>stream
x�+�r
�2P�01RI�r
�
�*T0T0

...

%%EOF
```

I manually parsed each multipart to get to its raw data.

I can easily convert the first part to XML, but for the second one,
How do I convert this to a "readable" PDF file?

I tried directly saving this to s3
with contentType: 'application/pdf'

```
await this.s3Client.saveS3Object(this.env.bucketname, `${name}.pdf`, pdfData, {
            contentType: 'application/pdf'
          });
```

And when I tried to open the pdf in S3, I just got a blank page.